# Refreshing the page takes a long time

Tags: asp.net

i don't know why when i click button (below) to delete data from gridview the page refreshes and take 5 ,6 seconds to appear with deleted data .

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonSuppEnfant"
                 runat="server"
                 Text="Supprimer"
                 Style="float: left;" Width="35px"
                 OnClick="ButtonSuppEnfant_Click"
                 CssClass="btn screenOnly"
                 DescriptionUrl="~/images/remove.png"
                 Height="28px"
                 ImageUrl="~/images/remove.png" />
```

when i put :

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    ............HTML code 
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and i click button 'delete' for exemple , the result is sooo fast i can see the line deleted in my gridview . the problem is that i can't remove this Tag becaune i need it in other operation

Thanks

Comment: Show server code that handles button click.It is impossible find problem having only it

Comment: plz show some code that handles refresh

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the button, your page do a PostBack, and you will call Page_Load again.

Make sure that your Page_Load is fast to execute. You can use IsPostBack to ignore some code on a PostBack

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
  // your code
  }
}
```

Comment: but my code is not in Page_Load

Comment: Wherever you code is there ..put ur code inside if(!IsPostBack)

Comment: i did it in my button code but it stay not refrech my grid when data is updated

Comment: and when i look in my BD data is not updated when i use if(!IsPostBack)
  { --code }

Comment: As they said, you should look into wrapping any databinding code you have in an `if(!IsPostBack)` statement. Unless you want every databound control to rebind on Page_Load.

Why can't you contain it within an update panel?

Comment: i did it ...all my server code is in 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
 <ContentTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
</asp:GridView>
```

BY DOING enableviewstate=”false” we make sure we are seeing updated data.!